# Arrow keys not working in php CLI script | EDIT: STDIN involved

Tags: terminal, stdin, php

i recently entered the fascinating world of PHP CLI.

I run then the script on an ubuntu terminal and when i pressed the arrows keys, instead of moving the cursor, it printed the escape codes ^[[A^[[B^[[C^[[D.

If i use the normal terminal the problem doesn't appear. So i guess that into my script something prevents the normal behaviour.

Does someone have any solution?

Thanks for the help!

EDIT:

Looks like it's STDIN, which I use to catch the inputs, the problem! When waiting for STDIN inputs, the terminal shows the wrong characters!!
How can I solve this?

Comment: Could you show us some code, please? [readline](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.readline.php) might be of some help if you're not already using it.

Comment: Uhm, is not a matter of code, when I press the arrow keys it shows one  of these [[A^[[B^[[D^[[C instead of moving the cursor!

Comment: Different implementations certainly result in different behaviour, at least for me. For example, with `fgets(STDIN)` or `fread(STDIN, 100)` I get the same escaped chars as you, whereas with `readline()`, which utilizes GNU readline, the left and right arrow keys allow line editing (this on a Linux box through a Windows PuTTY SSH terminal). Not sure if line editing is ever possible with `fgets` or `fread`, so I suspect you use `readline`. [Ncurses](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ncurses.php) is another possibility. But I'm afraid I'm not able to (try to) help much without seeing any code.

Comment: yes, i think you're right! the problem happens while the script is waiting for inputs from fgets(STDIN)!!! I didn't notice on the mac because i need a file path as input, and i used to drag and drop the needed file in the terminal. Instead when I drag and drop on on Ubuntu the terminal shows annoying ´ around the file path, so i need the arrows to move and delete those ´. This made the problem visible.
So how do we solve this? should i pass to readline()? PS: how can i solve the ´ problem? is there some way or should i just change my code to purge them? Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest replacing the `fgets(STDIN)` call with the [`readline()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readline.php) function, which is available at least in Linux environments. Note that the readline library is not shipped in OS X, although it can be installed separately.

```
// $input = fgets(STDIN);
$input = readline('Input: ');
```

If the only reason you need line editing is removing the surplus ´-characters from a drag and dropped file path, you can always trim any extra characters from the string in your script.

```
$input = readline('Input: ');
$input = trim($input, '´');
```

Comment: And it's **much** more user-friendly since you can use the cursor keys to navigate, have a history, etc.

Comment: So the only way is to install readline? I'll look for a way to install it without having to recompile the whole php. any suggestions?

Comment: @Bakaburg: Not sure if there's a really easy way to get `readline` working in OS X. Installation instructions using MacPorts [here](http://blog.jerodsanto.net/2009/06/php5-with-readline-support-on-os-x/). If you don't have MacPorts installed, go [here](http://www.macports.org/install.php) first. MacPorts in turn needs Apple's Xcode Developer Tools...